# Rename Directory inside Sdcard :Android Worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to rename a folder inside "sdcard/XYZ_APP/images/" "images" folder contains all the images inside it. i want to rename "images" folder to ".images" , like "mnt/sdcard/XYZ_APP/.images/.." so how can we do it in android worklight using javascript? i tried below code however i am sure there is something wrong in my code.please review this.

```
 function renamefile(){

var entry="sdcard/LMS_APP/images";
  DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry({fullPath: entry});
var parent = "sdcard/LMS_APP/";
DirectoryEntry  parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry({fullPath: parent});
 // move the file to a new directory and rename it
   Entry.moveTo(parentEntry, ".images", success, fail);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code works for me

```
/* Move /sdcard/Songs to /sdcard/Songs123 */
function renamefile(){
    var from = new DirectoryEntry("Songs", "/sdcard/Songs"); 
var  to =  new DirectoryEntry("Songs123", "/sdcard");
from.moveTo(to, "Songs123", success, failure);
}
```

So, try something on these lines

```
function renamefile(){
    var from = new DirectoryEntry("images", "/sdcard/LMS_APP/images"); 
    var  to =  new DirectoryEntry(".images", "/sdcard/LMS_APP");
    from.moveTo(to, ".images", success, failure);
}
```